# Encoding issue with email sent from form in ASP with Hebrew text

Tags: jquery, asp-classic, cdo.message

I'm using `CDO.Message` to send emails from a contact form on an ASP Classic website to the site owner. The site is in Hebrew and I've encoded everything with `UTF-8`.

My problem is that in Outlook 2007 the Hebrew sent from the form comes out in gibberish. Other text in Hebrew in the email (ie. hardcoded text) displays correctly.

I've checked these emails in Outlook 2010 and online at Gmail and all the Hebrew looks fine.

Of course my client has Outlook 2007 and is not likely to change anytime soon.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Here is the script for sending the emails:

```vb
Const CdoReferenceTypeName = 1
Dim objCDO, objBP
Set objCDO = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Message")
objCDO.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2 
objCDO.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "localhost"
objCDO.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25 
objCDO.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = False 
objCDO.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 60

objCDO.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1 'basic (clear-text) authentication
objCDO.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "aaaa@bbbbb.co.il"
objCDO.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "123456"
objCDO.Configuration.Fields.Update

objCDO.MimeFormatted = True
objCDO.To = email_to        
objCDO.Bcc = email_bcc
objCDO.From = email_from        

objCDO.Subject = email_subject      

objCDO.HTMLBody = email_body
objCDO.HTMLBodyPart.charset = "utf-8"
objCDO.BodyPart.charset = "utf-8"                                   

objCDO.Send
```

The form is submitted via the jquery malsup form plugin thus :

```
$('#contact_form').submit(function() {
    if (myvalidator.isValid()) {
        $(this).ajaxSubmit(function() { 
            $('#form_holder').html('thanks'); 
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

The form also has an attachment so is sent thusly:

```
<form action="inc_contact_send.asp" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="contact_form">
```

Comment: @Calon I don't know if I rejected by now 25 edits from you, please stop playing with tags..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try moving the:

```
objCDO.BodyPart.charset = "utf-8"
```

up a couple of lines so that it preceeds the assignment to `HTMLBody`.  It may also be worth you examining the content of `email_body` whilst debugging to be sure it contains the HTML you expect it should.

Comment: well, that was a surprise... at first it didn't seem to have made any difference, but now if i manually change the encoding of the received email in Outlook to UTF-8 then it displays everything correctly... thanks very much

Comment: i've noticed that putting charset line above the HTMLBody tag does in fact produce an error message "The requested body part was not found in this message."
the mail is actually sent out correctly (and with the correct encoding by the look of it).